# Send arguments to onMapReady Google Maps API Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm retrieving data as shown below. For each 'blocks' of data I need to add a marker on the Google Map I've set up. So is it possible to send the 'lat', 'lng' etc.. to the onMapReady method?

```
//the List to store the retrieved data
static List<infoToStore> info = new ArrayList<>();

public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot advertiser : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        final String catString = advertiser.child("cat").getValue(String.class);
        final String URLString = advertiser.child("downloadURL").getValue(String.class);
        final String keyString = advertiser.child("key").getValue(String.class);
        final String lat = advertiser.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
        final String lng = advertiser.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);
        final String descString = advertiser.child("serviceDesc").getValue(String.class);
        final String nameString = advertiser.child("serviceName").getValue(String.class);
        //populating the List
        info.add(new infoToStore(catString, URLString, keyString, lat, lng, descString, nameString));
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-20.285889,57.584607) , 10.0f) );
    for (infoToStore details: info){
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(getLat(), getLng())
                .title(getName())
                .snippet(getDesc())));
    }
}
```

the class infoToStore

```
public class infoToStore {
String cat;
String url;
String key;
String lat;
String lng;
String desc;
String name;

public infoToStore(String cat, String url, String key, String lat, String lng, String desc, String name) {
    this.cat = cat;
    this.url = url;
    this.key = key;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCat() {
    return this.cat;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return this.url;
}

public String getKey() {
    return this.key;
}

public String getLat() {
    return this.lat;
}

public String getLng() {
    return this.lng;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return this.desc;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
}
```

Comment: If `onDataChange` is called after the map loads, you can try checking `if (mMap != null)` then add the markers directly from `onDataChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `List<LatLng>` on your class and populate it using the coordinates you got on `onDataChange`

Then on `onMapReady`, you iterate over that list and add each point to the map

If you need more than the LatLng, to show the name for example, you should create a class with all the proprieties you want to save, like this:

```
public class InfoToStore {
    private LatLng latLng;
    private String name;

    InfoToStore(LatLng latLng, String name){
        this.latLng = latLng;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LatLng getLatLng(){
          return this.latLng;
    }

    public String getName(){
          return this.name;
    }
}
```

Inside your for on `onDataChange` do the following, after initializing the list:

```
listOfPoints.add(new InfoToStore(latLng, nameString))
```

Then just iterate inside `onMapReady` using `for(InfoToStore info: listOfPoints)` and with the info you have in `info` you add each point

Comment: that's exactly what I was thinking about, but the thing is each index of this list will have to contain all the 7 variables. I was thinking about a 2D arraylist but I'm getting confused on how to implement it

Comment: That's why you create a class with all the info you need, like I did in the example but with more information. Just add more variables to it like String descString and the others your need. Don't forget to add them to the constructor as well

Then when you read the contents, you create this new object with your info and add to the new list

Then when you iterate the list, you got all the info you need, since all List entries will have a item with that new class

Comment: If you need to search for a specific snapshot, using for example keyString, then instead of a List use a `HashMap<keyString, InfoToStore>`

Comment: do I need to initialize the List inside onDataChange? and for the for loop I'm getting error "Incompatible types - Required: java.lang.String"

Comment: You can initialize the list anywhere before you start adding elements to it.

Can you show me how you did it? It should be something like `List<ClassYouCreated> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: oh I got it now, I didn't create my List correctly. but how do I get each variable in the for loop to add markers? Do I need to set getters in the class I created?

Comment: I've completed the class code example with the getters. If you need to add more variables, just follow the same pattern: add the variable in the beginning, add it to the constructor and create it's getter.

Comment: that's what exactly I had done prior to the previous comment but in the onMapReady method it's saying "cannot resolve getLat(), getLng(), etc...

Comment: First, if you follow the best coding practises, the created class should start with uppercase. Rename it to InfoToStore. 

Then when you do there `for (infoToStore details: info)`, the variable `details` will hold the content you saved. So what you need to do is `details.getName()`, `details.getDesc` and so on..

Tip for improvement would be storing in InfoToStore an LatLng variable instead of 2 strings containing the lat and lng, so you can retrieve the LatLng right away.

Don't forget the mark the question answered if I helped